# Расшифровка текста

Tags: криптография

Всем привет, хочу расшифровать текст частотным анализом, подсчитал все буквы и сопоставил с теоретической частотой букв, но ничего не получилось.Помогите расшифровать,пожалуйста.

Вот текст:
яьажйпушцюдьбъйэбгюжфоьгпзъгиюъфьуюъвъджцебэдъвьбэщуйсдэзпуэяжбйщйкжфюьяждэвдэфъбэйфъбьдэщвэкчийаюьужгпйщжчийгюъъэфдьыэюъежбзгэыэкфьаэфшжкьъепюьыъгдэъгэабжуэуэкюьджзъддэваюэйгюьдйгуъэйгэюэшдэйгпаюъшфъуйъкэгъаъюпцвъдщгцгдьйгэщхжъгюэажзъйыжъфшцдкбжгъваъюьгцюьаэзгжгюжфоьгпкюьфцйэуоъбпйжщьыьыьщубьшдэйгпщгэбпыэзгэуиацйгжбуьгвэймъюцгэддцгъабьжащгпфъйщгбжгюэууэфиуаюэоъййъшжбэвцвэфцбсаюжебэйпжйаигьгпйъчщуюэбжвьвьеждъьыыцюьгдэкэфэеыэбпджыьэдяьвъхьъгжйаэбпяэуьддилвдэлыжйбэюэфьюъкъдъюьгэюаигьъгйщйджяжгпубьшдэйгпфэюьяцвдэкэцюэудщйгъабэвджзъкэдъаэфъбьъепыэдфжожэдъюьувэфцбъдъаюъфцйвэгюъдэдьвьюйътэбэфдэвидъфцвьбжзгэаюжфъгйщжячьубщгпйщэгжячигыьгъабьыаэйгэщддэвцюъуцйжкдьбжяьожжщчийгюэаюжуиыаэшьюдьщйжкдьбжяьожщуыэдоъыэдоэуяьвэбзьбьаэгэвцзгээкдщчэбпеъдъгйжкдьбжяьожщджяыэкэцюэудщыжйбэюэфьгэшъйыэюэяьгжтдъгьуэгйжкдьбжяьожжуийэыэлубьшдэйгжаэгюъчцъгйщдъыэгэюэъуюъвщюъкъдъюьгэюуэфияьуъюежбйуэжгюцфидьйъкэфдщяьуъюъхьбьэзъюъфдьщйжкдьбжяьожщэйдэудэлюъяъюуцьююъкъдъюьгэюьдьаэбджбйщыьыэлыэевьюгэшъвдъаюэчбъвыьаэвджгъйыьмьдфюыэгэюилщжяцуъзжбузъюьщаэуъйжбъкэдьйгэлыцаэйбъзъкэаъюъгьйыьбыдъвцдъйыэбпыэуъфъюуэфиэдйаэйэчъдуифъюшьгпфьубъджъуэяфцтьуэфдцьгвэймъюццшйгьыжвыэбжзъйгуэвуэфиэдфэбшъдйаюьужгпйщзъюгдцщжцйгьбуйсдэзпдьдэкьтаэюьжаэйаьгпщэгчиуьсуйгюьдцйдэууйьвэвюьфцшдэвдьйгюэъджжыьыэкэщдъаюжаэвдсйэуюъвъдгэкэйьвэкэеъйгэкэйэбьдьыэдъогэуйъжфъгаэвэъвцдьыэдъогэуйъжфъгаюъыюьйдэцвъдщуйъгьыжаэщужбйщеьдйдьуишжуьджъщд

Таблица подсчета и теория:[image: теория]
[image: Частота букв]

Comment: Ну так что не получилось? Переведите значения из синей таблички в проценты и стравните с левой табличкой

Comment: У вас ошибка в подсчете. Например, буква `я` в приведенном тексте встречается 22 раза, а не 44

Comment: Да, вы правы, произашла опечатка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Расшифрованный текст:

ДА  ВРЕМЕНИ УШЛО НЕМАЛО. Я ВСЮ НОЧЬ ВОЗИЛСЯ С ГИДРАЗИНОМ НО ДЕЛО СДЕЛАНО Я МОГ БЫ СПРАВИТЬСЯ И БЫСТРЕЕ ОДНАКО РЕШИЛ ЧТО КОГДА ПОДЖИГАЕШЬ РАКЕТНОЕ ТОПЛИВО В ОГРАНИЧЕННОМ ПРОСТРАНСТВЕ, ОСТОРОЖНОСТЬ — ПРЕЖДЕ ВСЕГО ТЕПЕРЬ У МЕНЯ ТУТ НАСТОЯЩИЕ ТРОПИЧЕСКИЕ ДЖУНГЛИ.ТЕМПЕРАТУРА ПОЧТИ 30 °C  А КАКАЯ ВЛАЖНОСТЬ Я ТОЛЬКО ЧТО ВЫПУСТИЛ В АТМОСФЕРУ ТОННУ ТЕПЛА И 50 ЛИТРОВ ВОДЫ В ПРОЦЕССЕ ЖИЛОМУ МОДУЛЮ ПРИШЛОСЬ ИСПЫТАТЬ СЕБЯ В РОЛИ МАМАШИ НЕАККУРАТНОГО ДОШКОЛЬНИКА ОН ЗАМЕЩАЕТ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАННЫЙ МНОЙ КИСЛОРОД  А РЕГЕНЕРАТОР ПЫТАЕТСЯ СНИЗИТЬ ВЛАЖНОСТЬ ДО РАЗУМНОГО УРОВНЯ С ТЕПЛОМ НИЧЕГО НЕ ПОДЕЛАЕШЬ КОНДИЦИОНЕРА В МОДУЛЕ НЕ ПРЕДУСМОТРЕНО НА МАРСЕ ХОЛОДНО  МЫ НЕ ДУМАЛИ  ЧТО ПРИДЕТСЯ ИЗБАВЛЯТЬСЯ ОТ ИЗБЫТКА ТЕПЛА К ПОСТОЯННОМУ РЕВУ СИГНАЛИЗАЦИИ Я БЫСТРО ПРИВЫК  ПОЖАРНАЯ СИГНАЛИЗАЦИЯ В КОНЦЕ КОНЦОВ ЗАМОЛЧАЛА ПОТОМУ ЧТО ОГНЯ БОЛЬШЕ НЕТ СИГНАЛИЗАЦИЯ НИЗКОГО УРОВНЯ КИСЛОРОДА ТОЖЕ СКОРО ЗАТИХНЕТ А ВОТ СИГНАЛИЗАЦИИ ВЫСОКОЙ ВЛАЖНОСТИ ПОТРЕБУЕТСЯ НЕКОТОРОЕ ВРЕМЯ РЕГЕНЕРАТОР ВОДЫ ЗАВЕРШИЛ СВОИ ТРУДЫ НА СЕГОДНЯ ЗАВЕРЕЩАЛА ОЧЕРЕДНАЯ СИГНАЛИЗАЦИЯ  ОСНОВНОЙ РЕЗЕРВУАР РЕГЕНЕРАТОРА НАПОЛНИЛСЯ  КАКОЙ КОШМАР ТОЖЕ МНЕ ПРОБЛЕМКА ПОМНИТЕ СКАФАНДР  КОТОРЫЙ Я ИЗУВЕЧИЛ ВЧЕРА Я ПОВЕСИЛ ЕГО НА СТОЙКУ ПОСЛЕ ЧЕГО ПЕРЕТАСКАЛ К НЕМУ НЕСКОЛЬКО ВЕДЕР ВОДЫ ОН СПОСОБЕН ВЫДЕРЖАТЬ ДАВЛЕНИЕ ВОЗДУХА В ОДНУ АТМОСФЕРУ УЖ С ТАКИМ КОЛИЧЕСТВОМ ВОДЫ ОН ДОЛЖЕН СПРАВИТЬСЯ ЧЕРТ НУ Я И УСТАЛ  ВСЮ НОЧЬ НА НОГАХ ПОРА И ПОСПАТЬ Я ОТБЫВАЮ В СТРАНУ СНОВ В САМОМ РАДУЖНОМ НАСТРОЕНИИ  КАКОГО Я НЕ ПРИПОМНЮ СО ВРЕМЕН ТОГО САМОГО ГО СОЛА НАКОНЕЦ-ТО ВСЕ ИДЕТ ПО-МОЕМУ  НАКОНЕЦ-ТО ВСЕ ИДЕТ ПРЕКРАСНО У МЕНЯ ВСЕ-ТАКИ ПОЯВИЛСЯ ШАНС НА ВЫЖИВАНИЕ